# How to use Excel to count data in rows

Tags: excel

May I know if it's possible for Excel to count data in a row? For example in the table below I would be glad to know how Excel can count only the following "A1", "B2", "B3" "C4", "C5", "C6" from Cells **E2** to **L2** and record in the REMARKS column. That's if a candidate obtains either "A1" or "B2" or "B3", etc. it counts them as the number of passes. In this example, the number of passes obtained is 3. ("A1", "B2", "B3")

[Excel Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lxl5.png)

Comment: COUNTIFS perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use both SUM and COUNTIFS (or countif) together. Here's the formula, adjust range as needed:

```
D2 formula from screenshot:  =SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:C2,{"A1","B2","B3","C4","C5","C6"}))
```

[image]